# IIS 8 Site opening wrong website

Tags: iis-8, siebel

We have deployed 3 Siebel (Oralce CRM package application) websites on Win 2012, IIS 8.

Each of these 3 websites have separate aliases and they use separate host header.
Each of the 3 websites, have their own Application pools also.
On the DNS, crmdev, crmtest and crmuat all point to 10.x.x.x. (same IP)

```
Host header Alias       IP  
crmdev     -         10.x.x.x
crmtest    -         10.x.x.x
crmuat     -         10.x.x.x
```

All the websites, have epublicsector_oui_enu application in them.

Issue:
We have observed, that SOMETIMES when we try to open http://crmuat/epublicsector_oui_enu , the Test application opens up (instead of UAT).
But after we do a Test and UAT application pool restart and Test and UAT Website restart, it works fine for some time.
But all of a sudden after few hours/days, the issue re-occurs.
There is no specific time or duration after which this happens.

Siebel has specific handler mappings, which are pointing correctly on the physical server path.

Can you please guide as to what is it that is causing this?

Regards
Jim

[IIS8 websites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh1Pj.jpg)

Comment: So - if I understand correctly - you occasionally experience traffic to  http://crmuat/epublicsector_oui_enu going to  http://crmtest/epublicsector_oui_enu ? But only occasionally? Have you tried to look at the network traffic and request/response information when this happens to ensure that it's not a redirect that's happening or similar? Also try adding some different simple html or text files on each domain that's distinguishably different and then the next time this happens - can you then access these other files to ensure it's not something in browser or proxy etc?

Comment: Yes @AllanS.Hansen, instead of UAT, Test application is opening. But only occasionally. It is becoming difficult to debug as it is not happening consistently. I have added a simple html page on the two website folder and will try to open them, when this issue next occurs

Comment: I have noticed that the Handler mapping at the Server level and site level are pointing to wrong dll. But the Handler mapping at application level is set correctly. Can some one tell me, which one will be effective ? Like if we have different values set at Server, Site and application level, which value is effective?

Comment: We were able to resolve it by pointing the 2 Siebel handler mappings (Swef,swe) at Site level &  application level to point to respective (Dev,Test,UAT) dll file.